# Simulating this dropdown animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How can I simulate the following dropdown animation effect:

http://i.imgur.com/jUp9Isu.gif

Here's the JSFiddle I have: http://jsfiddle.net/52VtD/11704/

HTML:

```
<div class="dropdown">
  <a href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="true">
    Dropdown
    <span class="caret"></span>
  </a>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
    <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Action</a></li>
    <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Another action</a></li>
    <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Something else here</a></li>
    <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Separated link</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
@import url('http://getbootstrap.com/dist/css/bootstrap.css');

body {
    margin: 50px;
}

.dropdown-menu {
    top: 0;
    border-radius: 0;
}

.dropdown-menu li a {
    padding: 10px 25px;
    font-size: 12px;
}
```

Comment: See https://gist.github.com/orizens/4994397 and a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/khfh656L/